# Не работает TemplatedParent

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть стиль для кнопки

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,1,0,0" />
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DockPanel>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Path=(attached:ImageProperties.Image), RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                               DockPanel.Dock="{Binding Path=(attached:ImageProperties.ImagePosition), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"
                               Margin="2"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="2">
                        <TextBlock.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="Text" Value="">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </TextBlock.Resources>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

В таком виде он не работает (не отображается картинка). Работает только тогда, когда у картинки свойство

```
Source="{Binding Path=(attached:ImageProperties.Image), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TemplateBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc189062(v=vs.95).aspx) предназначен и работает только в [ControlTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.controltemplate(v=vs.110).aspx), в `DataTemplate` он не работает(`TemplatedParent` в этом плане, ничем не отличается)